# How to update distributed cache under high traffic and multiple applications?

Tags: caching, redis, race-condition, distributed-caching

I have N services that use M redis as the remote distributed cache. Suppose now multiple services want to retrieve the same key, and the following pseudo codes are how the work is done:

```
redisClient = getRedisClientByConsistentHash(key)
value = redisClient.get(key)
if value not exist
    value = getValueFromSomewhereElse(key) // line4
    redisClient set key value ex 1 nx // line5
return value
```

So the problem is:

In "line4", if 2 applications retrieve different values, one is newer and the other is old(should be deprecated), it's possible that the call to store the old value will happen before the call to store the new value, thus the new value won't be stored in redis. If we introduce some distributed lock mechanism, the problem still remains.

Answer (score 0):

If the Key Storage internally makes use of timestamp of key in a way such that if KeyA is required to be updated from ValueA to ValueB then this updation is possible only if ValueB is inserted at a time which is greater than last updated timestamp of KeyA. Then its guaranteed that only new values will be inserted in a particular Key Storage. OldValues cannot overwrite NewValues (Timestamp Based Protocol). (Don't know whether redis follows Timestamp Based Protocol).

Both of your 2 applications (say, A, B) tried to fetch key from their respective primary `redisClient` and did not find the key and hence they went to fetch the key from `SomewhereElse` and found the key, but A has old and B has new. In such case there are few questions:

```
1. What if A's or B's primary `redisClient` itself gave you a value which is old?
2. How you come to know the value which is fetched is old or new?
```

Solutions:

```
1. Use a value which has majority (i.e the value received from atleast [ceil(M+1)/2] redisClients). Ofcourse this involves querying atleast [ceil(M+1)/2] rediClients which seems expensive.  (Paxos Theorem)
2. Depending upon application logic, most of the time you don't require latest values. That is, if the application requirement is to just check the presence of a value then it does not matter whether the value is old or new.
```

Comment: Redis seems lacking of such timestamp based protocol.